# SQL Delete statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
include_once 'dbfunction.php';
getDbConnect();

mysqli_query("DELETE FROM crewlist WHERE id = $_GET[crew_id]") or die (mysqli_error());
echo 'Delete success';
header ('Location: crewlisting.php');
```

This code doesn't work, however when I replace the crew_id with the actual primary key via hard coding the delete function works

Comment: If you're using mysqli, then start learning about [prepared statements/bind variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)..... you have an enormous security hole here

Comment: 4 things wrong with this piece of code, possibly 5.

Comment: Yeah @MarkBaker "if/when" that piece of code ever makes it off the ground.

Comment: *"This code doesn't work, however when I replace the crew_id with the actual primary key via hard coding the delete function works"* - I find that rather hard to believe, not with PHP it won't. In phpmyadmin, sure. But not with what you posted, that's for sure.

Comment: `dbfunction.php` <= Pandora's box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this (`MySQLi Procedural`)

In `dbfunction.php` should be

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

and insert page should be

```
<?
    include ("dbfunction.php"); //include db connection

    $id = $_REQUEST['crew_id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM crewlist WHERE id = '$id' ";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Errors are

1. There is no function define in `getDbConnect()`
2. If you are confusing with `'`and `"` then split the functions

   ```
   $id = $_REQUEST['crew_id'];
   $sql = "DELETE FROM crewlist WHERE id = '$id' ";
   ```
3. Use `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_error` in correct format
4. and error in  `mysqli_query`, You are not passing connection to `MySQLi`
5. When ever database part is Finished, Close connection  `mysqli_close($conn);`

Comment: @forumzeon1 Just copy this code and replace with yours

Comment: I'm not much of a fan for drop-in code. It doesn't outline where the errors are, and future visitors to the question will ask themselves the same thing.

Comment: you're welcome, however look at their `echo/header` ;-) Plus, we don't know how/where they are using their `$_GET[crew_id]` array, making that question all the more harder to know for sure if your answer will solve it. Oh, and the fact that they're not passing db connection to the query. Maybe they're doing that in an `if()` conditional, but haven't shown us. Their question, far as I'm concerned is way too unclear for my taste to have submitted an answer. I'm just hoping we'll be seeing a green tick next to yours ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score -1):

Correct your query:

```
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM crewlist WHERE id ='".$_GET['crew_id']."'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
```